# How to read data from zk9500 fingerprint device in python language

Tags: python, sdk, protocols, fingerprint

My project is fingerprint recognition using the zk9500 device and Python programming language.

I am writing a code to read the fingerprint and compare it with the database, but I can't read the data from the fingerprint device by code without using SDK.

I searched in `pyzatt`, `pyzk`, and `libzk` libraries, and I couldn't find instructions that read data directly from the fingerprint device.

I found some instructions that read data from ZKTeco devices but it needs an IP address and PORT, while zk9500 doesn't have any IP address. However, it connects to the computer by USB.

Comment: "*I can't read the data from the fingerprint device by code without using SDK*" It's not clear based on the information you've provided here why the SDK is a deal-breaker.

Comment: Because it is a stage of an electronic lock project that recognizes on the image, then the sound, and then the fingerprint.
I create GUI for this. Therefore, I want to call a code to read the fingerprint and identify it when I press the fingerprint recognition button.

Comment: Why does any of that preclude using the SDK?

Comment: I am very sorry for my late. Because there is no python demo for the ZK9500 .

Comment: Just because there’s no demo for your particular model doesn’t mean that you can’t use the SDK, can you elaborate further?

Comment: @ShadiMar Have you read [this link](https://github.com/adrobinoga/zk-protocol/blob/master/protocol.md#protocol-overview) before? Apparently, it's mentioned that you can read data over USB as well.

Comment: @ShadiMar And why you don't use its SDK as you mentioned? Apparently, there isn't any SDK for Linux? is it?

Comment: @ShadiMar I also tested with the `pyzk` library through TCP connection properly.